# ternary-operator `'messege' in order` returns true but it still does not show anything in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, javascript-objects, conditional-operator

I am trying to print `order.messege` if it exists in `order` object
here are the `console.logs`
[image]

```
          <div>
                { typeof(orderData) !== 'undefined' && orderData !== null ?
                    <div>
                        {orderData.reverse().map( (order, index) => {
                            console.log('messege' in order)
                            console.log(order)
                            { 'messege' in order ?
                                <div>
                                    <h1>{order.messege}</h1>
                                </div>
                               :
                               <div>
                                    <h1>roll back</h1>
                               </div>

                            }
                            } 
                        )}
                    </div>
                    :
                    <h1>no orders</h1>
                }
         </div>
```

Comment: Your `map` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: You've got a block, but no `return` statement. Don't mix up JSX syntax with JS functions

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed to `map` should return some JSX that you want to render for each element. You are not returning anything, so it evaluates to `undefined`. Here is the complete JSX for the `div` in question:

```js
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(orderData) && orderData.length ? (
        <div>
          {orderData.reverse().map((order, index) => {
            console.log("messege" in order);
            console.log(order);

            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1>{"messege" in order ? order.messege : "roll back"}</h1>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>no orders</h1>
      )}
    </div>
```